# How to resolve this issue when building a docker image of a Django app

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my django app but I'm having an issue where the CMD isn't recognizing the "python3" command.

I created the requirements.txt, Dockerfile and .dockerignore file in the root directory and the Dockerfile contains the follow:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [
    "python3",
    "manage.py",
    "runserver",
    "0.0.0.0:8000"
]
```

I'm using VS Code and the intellisense is highlighting all the items in the CMD list as an error.
When I try to build the image, I'm getting the following error:

**Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 12: unknown instruction: "PYTHON3",**

Can anyone provide any possible solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Because docker doesn't support not inline commands natively.

You should do it like this:

```
CMD [              \
    "python3",     \
    "manage.py",   \
    "runserver",   \
    "0.0.0.0:8000" \
]

# OR

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Realized that a minute after I posted this. Thank You!